# Pass parameter in bat file to run from desktop short cut

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a bat file from a desktop shortcut and pass a parameter to it.
I can run it from DOS with no problem.

When I try to run it from a desktop shortcut, I can enter the parameter, but it does not get passed.
I enter a file name like 20200103.txt and the bat file takes the .txt extension off so that only the first part of the file is used later in the bat file

Here are the first couple lines that I am using in the bat file

```
SET /I %1 DTE = %1
set %~n1 = %1%
ECHO %1
ECHO %1%
ECHO %~n1%
```

Is there any way to include a document when I submit a question?

Comment: You definitely need to open a Command Prompt window, type `set /?`, press the 'enter' key, and read the information presented.

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing an argument for a file in a shortcut, you need to surround it with "" so if you want to pass 20200103.txt as arg 1 to the batch file you would put in the shortcut *path\thing\thing\file "20200103.txt"*. Also, your code may not be working properly because /I is not an option is the "set" command. Like compo said, try checking out `set /?`